# C++11 / VS2010 : Returning containers of uncopyable but movable objects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, move-semantics

Consider the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>

struct A : private boost::noncopyable
{
  A(int num, const std::string& name)
    : num(num),
      name(name)
  {
  }

  A(A&& other)
    : num(other.num),
      name(std::move(other.name))
  {
  }

  int num;
  std::string name;
};

std::vector<A> getVec()
{
  std::vector<A> vec;
  vec.emplace_back(A(3, "foo"));
  // vec.emplace_back(3, "foo"); not available yet in VS10?

  return vec; // error, copy ctor inaccessible
}

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  // should call std::vector::vector(std::vector&& other)
  std::vector<A> vec = getVec();

  return 0;
}
```

This does not compile under VS2010 because obviously `A` is `noncopyable` and thus `std::vector<A>` cannot be copied. Accordingly I cannot return a `std::vector<A>` from a function.

However it doesn't feel right to me that this sort of thing is not possible considering the concept of RVO. If Return Value Optimization was applied here, copy construction could be omitted and the call to `getVec()` would be valid.

So what would be the proper way to do this? Is this possible at all in VS2010 / C++11?

Comment: RVO does not remove the requirement that things be copyable.

Comment: The order of the data members in your member initialization lists (first `num`, then `name`) do not match the order of the declarations of the data members at the bottom of the class (first `name`, then `num`). In general, this can lead to very surprising bugs, so I would always strife to make the orders consistent.

Comment: Also, `std::vector<A> vec = getVec();` is *not* an assignment, but an *initialization* (copy initialization, to be exact).

Comment: Try adding a move assignment operator.  That makes it compile for me in GCC. (though my error is in a different place)

Comment: @FredOverflow: You are right about those two things, thanks. Fixed now, since it doesn't have anything to do with the actual question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `return vec;` does not compile, VS2010 does not support move semantics fully yet. Normally, automatic variables are moved implicitly if returned from a function. Use `return std::move(vec);` as an interim workaround, and make a note in your head to get rid of the `std::move` in the future.

A full explanation can be found [in this FAQ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540204/) under the headline "Moving out of functions".

Also, your two-argument constructor makes a copy of the string argument which is passed by reference-to-const. I would suggest taking the argument by value instead and moving it into the member:

```
A(int num, std::string name) : num(num), name(std::move(name)) { }
```

This way, you minimize the number of necessary copies. See [Want Speed? Pass by Value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) for details.

Also, since your move constructor doesn't do anything special, you can `default` it:

```
A(A&& other) = default;
```

This makes it more robust in the face of changes. Bugs seldomly hide in the code you don't write :)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it's a VS2010 issue. However, std::move does not fix the problem. Although, as Benjamin Lindley stated in the comments, adding a move assignment operator does indeed fix it for VS2010.

Comment: @Opossum Really? Why does assignment matter? `std::vector<A> vec = getVec();` is not an assignment.

Comment: Well I guess the vector's elements are moved using the move assignment operator. Adding `A::A& operator=(A&& other)` makes it compile.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I don't know what error he was getting, but mine was with the usage of emplace_back, not with returning the object or the initialization in main.  Adding the move assignment operator fixed it.

Comment: Strangely enough, emplace_back() worked fine for me. The issue was returning a `std::vector<A>`. The error was `error C2248: 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::operator =' : cannot access private member` when returning `vec`. Changing the return type to void and not returning anything works fine even without an move assignment operator.

Comment: Also the `= default` keyword doesn't seem to have been implemented in VS2010 yet. Man, I can't wait for VS2012.

Comment: @Opossum Well, then keep waiting, VS2012 doesn't bring it either. It doesn't bring many new things, not even such rather simple things like defaulted and deleted functions or delegating and inheriting constructors.

Answer (score 6):

> However it doesn't feel right to me that this sort of thing is not possible considering the concept of RVO.

Elision, the general term for stuff like named return value optimization, is an optimization. It is not *required*. The specification *allows* it, but doesn't force any implementation to do it even when it is allowed to.

As such, to enforce consistency between compilers that allow elision and those that don't, if elision is allowed by an operation, the compiler ***must*** still verify that the copy/move being elided would be *possible* given the current state of the code. So if a copy/move constructor is not accessible, the operation fails even if the compiler won't actually call it.

In this case, Visual Studio 2010 seems to be kind of confused in this regard. It does recognize that `return vec;` should move from `vec`. However, it seems that VS2010's `std::vector` implementation needs a move assignment operator to move; without one, it will attempt to copy.

Comment: Wrong, normally the vector should be automatically moved in the function.

Comment: But the move constructor *is* accessible.