# Moving a boost::ptr_vector

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, move-semantics, boost-ptr-container

Given a type which is non-copyable but movable, I am trying to construct a `boost::ptr_vector` of this type and return it from a function. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

```
struct NonCopyableButMovable
{
    using this_type = NonCopyableButMovable;

    this_type() {}

    this_type(this_type const &) = delete;
    this_type & operator =(this_type const &) = delete;

    this_type(this_type &&) {} // no default move ctr in VS2013
    this_type & operator =(this_type &&) {} // no default move assignment in VS2013
};

boost::ptr_vector<NonCopyableButMovable> make_ptr_vector()
{
    boost::ptr_vector<NonCopyableButMovable> res;
    //return res; // (1)
    //return std::move(res); // (2)
    return boost::ptr_vector<NonCopyableButMovable>(); // (3)
}
```

I can only get (3) to compile: the temporary `ptr_vector` gets moved. With (1) and (2), the compiler calls `boost::new_clone` which attempts to call `NonCopyableButMovable`'s copy constructor.

According to [this FAQ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics/11540204#11540204), section "Moving out of functions", (1) should work, i.e. `res` should be moved, not copied.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608490/c11-vs2010-returning-containers-of-uncopyable-but-movable-objects), (2) can be used as a workaround for compilers that are not fully standard-conformant, but for a reason I don't understand, `boost::new_clone` also gets called with (2).

Note that if I replace `boost::ptr_vector` with `std::vector`, the three ways of returning compile fine.

Is there something broken in Boost ptr_containers' move semantics with VS2013? What happens in case (2)? What would be a workaround to implement such a ptr_container factory function?

Comment: From looking at the [boost pointer container docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) it looks like a fairly old library.  It looks like it simply isn't compatible with c++11 move semantics.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Thank you! Sadly, this might be the answer. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657518/boost-pointer-container-made-obsolete-by-stdunique-ptr-in-c11-14) I thought the library was still relevant in C++11/14.